# Is `textAlign` value automatically reversed in RTL mode?

Tags: react-native, right-to-left, left-to-right

My question is: if I set the alignment in a `Text` component like this:
`textAlign: "left"`
Now, if I force RTL mode (I18nManager), will it automatically convert the style to `textAlign: "right"` ?